# Get list of combinations for K groups of N members and L groups of M members

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, combinations

**In Python; what is the best way to get a list of combinations for `k` groups of `n` members and `l` groups of `m` members given a list of possible members `g`?**

Example, given a list of elements:

```
g = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
```

What I want is to have a list `li` of all combinations for e.g. 2(=`k`) groups of 2(=`n`) and 1(=`l`) group of 3(=`m`):

```
[["AB", "CD", "EFG"],
 ["AC", "BD", "EFG"],
 ["AD", "CB", "EFG"],
 ["AE", "CD", "BFG"],
 ["AF", "CD", "BEG"],... ]
```

1. **I don't want any repetition of elements accross any of the groups** (equivalent of saying: I want every different element to appear once accross all the groups for every different combination).

   > E.g. `["AB", "AD", "EFG"]` is not a valid combination as it has the element `A` more than once accross all groups.
2. **I don't want different permutations inside a group**;

   > E.g. `["AB", "CD", "EFG"]` should not be repeated in a form like `["BA", "DC", "EGF"]`.
3. Also, **if a combination appears in any of the `k-groups` I don't want that same combination in the k-groups if the `l-groups` are just the same (and same for `l-groups`)**.

   > E.g. if`["AB", "CD", "EFG"]` appears, `[ "CD", "AB", "EFG"]` should not appear again.

To be clear, I'm only interested in the case where the groups will always fit neatly/exactly in the total group of elements to be used(`g`):

> E.g. `2x2 + 1x3 == 7 == len(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"])`, `1x2 + 1x3 == 5 == len(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])`.

---

I could use [Python's permutations function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and just group together in `k` groups of `n` and `l` groups of `m` in each permutation, but I will have a lot of unnecessary iterations for more elements.

Comment: Can you duplicate elements within one string?  For instance, is it legal to have `["AB", "BC", "EFE"]`?

Comment: Nope. No element can be repeated in another subgroup.

Comment: Fix your posting?  You already have **B** and **C** repeated in some examples, such as `["AB", "BC", "EFG"]`

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Given your clarification, the answer I posted is wrong: it emits duplicates across groups.  This problem isn't as straightforward as it first appeared: each group has to be a *combination* from the lexicon, and you need all *mutually exclusive* permutations of the groups.

Comment: Do you want both `["AB", "CD", "EFG"]` and `["CD", "AB", "EFG"]` or just one of them?

Comment: @rici 5: just one of them. It doesn't matter if e.g. `AB` (same as `BA`) is in the first group of two or the second one, just in **a group of two** (vs group of three).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Code edited to meet updated requirement (rule 3).

Code:

```
import itertools as it


def unique_group(iterable, k, n):
    """Return an iterator, comprising groups of size `k` with combinations of size `n`."""
    # Build separate combinations of `n` characters
    groups = ("".join(i) for i in it.combinations(iterable, n))    # 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', ...

    # Build unique groups of `k` by keeping the longest sets of characters
    return (i for i in it.combinations(groups, k) 
                if len(set("".join(i))) == sum((map(len, i))))     # ('AB', 'CD'), ('AB', 'CE'), ... 


def combined(groups1, groups2):
    """Return an iterator with unique combinations of groups (k and l)."""
    # Build a unique cartesian product of groups `k` and `l`, filtering non-disjoints
    return (i[0] + i[1]
               for i in it.product(groups1, groups2) 
               if set("".join(i[0])).isdisjoint(set("".join(i[-1]))))


iterable = "ABCDEFG"
g1 = unique_group(iterable, 2, 2)
g2 = unique_group(iterable, 1, 3)
result = list(combined(g1, g2))
print(len(result))
result
```

Output:

```
105

[('AB', 'CD', 'EFG'),
 ('AB', 'CE', 'DFG'),
 ...,
 ('BC', 'AD', 'EFG'),
 ('BC', 'AE', 'DFG'),
 ...,
]
```

Details and insight can be found in a [demonstration](https://repl.it/KHEz/2).

Comment: I think you are nearly there. Trying this for e.g. `iterable = "ABCDE"` with `g1 = unique_group(iterable, 1, 2)` and `g2 = unique_group(iterable, 1, 3)` results in `[('AD', 'BCE'), ('AE', 'BCD'), ('BC', 'ADE'), ('BD', 'ACE'), ('BE', 'ACD'), ('CD', 'ABE'), ('CE', 'ABD'), ('DE', 'ABC')]`. This is e.g. missing the combinations `('AB', 'CDE')` and `('AC', 'BDE')`.

Comment: With your new input, I get all of those combinations (a list of 10 items).

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit: after clarification, I added a line that should complete the solution...

How about this, which uses several [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) and the [flatten recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). Anyhow, I think itertools.combinations is what you want to use:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain, product

def flatten(listOfLists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)

lico = lambda li,x: list( combinations(li,x) ) 
def get_funky_groups( elements, k,n,l,m ):     
    kn = lico( lico(elements,n),k)  # k groups of n elements
    lm = lico( lico( elements,m), l)  # l groups of m elements
    results =  [map( lambda x: "".join(x), flatten(r)) for r in product(kn, lm)]
    # added this line so that only each element was used once.. 
    return [ r for r in results if len(set( flatten( r))) == len(g) ]
```

For your example list, this yields **105** results

```
In [3]: g = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

In [4]: results = get_funky_groups(g, 2,2,1,3)

In [5]: results[:10]
Out[5]: 
[['AB', 'CD', 'EFG'],
 ['AB', 'CE', 'DFG'],
 ['AB', 'CF', 'DEG'],
 ['AB', 'CG', 'DEF'],
 ['AB', 'DE', 'CFG'],
 ['AB', 'DF', 'CEG'],
 ['AB', 'DG', 'CEF'],
 ['AB', 'EF', 'CDG'],
 ['AB', 'EG', 'CDF'],
 ['AB', 'FG', 'CDE']]

In [6]: len( results) 
Out[6]: 105

In [7]: g = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

In [8]: results = get_funky_groups(g, 1,2,1,3)

In [9]: results
Out[9]: 
[['AB', 'CDE'],
 ['AC', 'BDE'],
 ['AD', 'BCE'],
 ['AE', 'BCD'],
 ['BC', 'ADE'],
 ['BD', 'ACE'],
 ['BE', 'ACD'],
 ['CD', 'ABE'],
 ['CE', 'ABD'],
 ['DE', 'ABC']]
```

Probably you dont want an answer that relies on having string elements

```
def get_funky_groups_anyhashable( elements, k,n,l,m ):     
    kn = lico( lico(elements,n),k)  # k groups of n elements
    lm = lico( lico( elements,m), l)  # l groups of m elements
    results =  [ list(flatten(r)) for r in product(kn, lm)]
    # added this line so that only each element was used once.. 
    return [ r for r in results if len(set( flatten( r))) == len(g) ]

In [103]: g = ["A1", "B2", 232, "D0", 32]

In [104]: get_funky_groups_anyhashable(g, 1,2,1,3)
Out[104]: 
[[('A1', 'B2'), (232, 'D0', 32)],
 [('A1', 232), ('B2', 'D0', 32)],
 [('A1', 'D0'), ('B2', 232, 32)],
 [('A1', 32), ('B2', 232, 'D0')],
 [('B2', 232), ('A1', 'D0', 32)],
 [('B2', 'D0'), ('A1', 232, 32)],
 [('B2', 32), ('A1', 232, 'D0')],
 [(232, 'D0'), ('A1', 'B2', 32)],
 [(232, 32), ('A1', 'B2', 'D0')],
 [('D0', 32), ('A1', 'B2', 232)]]
```

Also worth noting , in case performance becomes issue

```
In [132]: lico( combinations( g,2),1) == lico( lico( g,2),1 )
Out[132]: True
```

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear but this isn't what I'm looking for. E.g. your first iterations `['AB', 'AC', 'ABC']`: you can only have each element once, so you can't have more than one `A`',  more than one `B`, more than one `C` accross any of the groups. (I edited the original post; see rule #1).

Comment: Hmm, I think then you can just check the set of flattened elements, as indicated in the simple edit I added. By using the ```combinations``` tool you already do much fewer iterations than you would with the ```permutations``` itertool that you linked to.. but you can maybe optimize further...

Answer (score 0):

This problem isn't as straightforward as it first appeared: each group has to be a *combination* from the lexicon, and you need all *mutually exclusive* permutations of the groups.

I think this will require that you write a recursive generator, taking the alphabet and the size list.  Something like the following code (which I'm afraid I haven't tested ... ):

```
def foo(lexicon, size_list, result):
    if len(size_list) == 0:
        yield result
        return
    size = size_list[0]
    for group in itertools.combinations(lexicon, size):
        # remove used items from the lexicon
        next_lex = lexicon[:]
        for item in group:
            next_lex.remove(item)
        # recur at next level
        foo(next_lex, size_list[1:], result + [group] )

foo( "ABCDEFG", [2, 2, 3], [] )
```

Comment: Returns an empty generator.